# Equality of two lists of variables

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

How to define a meta-logical predicate that tests (thus succeeds or fails only) if two lists of unique variables contain exactly the same variables using [the built-ins](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo) from the current ISO standard (ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995 including [Cor.2](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2)).

Stated differently, the predicate should succeed if one list of unique variables is a permutation of the other. In analogy to [`library(ordsets)`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dordsets.html#lib_002dordsets), let's call this meta-logical predicate  `varset_seteq(As, Bs).`

Note that, in contrast to `ord_seteq/2`, this predicate cannot be simply `As == Bs`.

Comment: Should the predicate fail if any of its two arguments is not a list of unique variables?

Comment: Just waiting, maybe there are more and different answers.

Comment: I was trying something different, but I had to check if `As` and `Bs` really are sets of free variables. In my answer that is guaranteed by the fact that they must unify with the second argument of `term_variables/2`.

Comment: No, it is not guaranteed, you have to assume it, too.  `varset_seteq([A+B,a],[])` succeeds in many systems (by default). ... and unifies the arguments.

Comment: I understand why. Thank you. I added this observation to my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution I propose uses `term_variables/2` to check if `Bs` has no extra variables over `As` and that `As` has no variable that doesn't appear in `Bs`.

```
varset_seteq(As, Bs):-
    term_variables(As-Bs, As),
    term_variables(Bs-As, Bs).
```

---

The above solution can be tricked to succeed with arguments that are not sets of free variables:

```
 | ?- varset_seteq([A], [a]).

 A = a

 yes
```

To avoid that, unification can be replaced with equivalence test:

```
varset_seteq(As, Bs):-
    term_variables(As-Bs, A0),
    A0 == As,
    term_variables(Bs-As, B0),
    B0 == Bs.
```

Comment: Your counterexample is really the best! It's a pity, because otherwise `term_variables/2` could exploit the fact that it has to check the wellformedness of its second argument anyway, so counting its length is free which then might be used to fail earlier.

Comment: I like this approach! But don't you also need to check if the lists are just bars? I'm not by my computer at the moment, but wouldn't `varset_seteq([A,B,a], [A,B])` succeed?

Comment: No, it doesn't succeed. What is a bar?

Comment: Oh yeah. My bad. I brain short circuited. I see: because you test each list of term-vars against the respective lists. Very nice solution, I think. a bar is a typo for var. sorry :)

Answer (score 7):

If we may assume that the two lists contain unique variables, then the following use of double negation works:

```
varset_seteq(As, Bs) :-
    \+ \+ (numbered_from(As, 1),
           sort(Bs, SBs),
           As == SBs).

numbered_from([], _).
numbered_from([X|Xs], X) :-
    X1 is X + 1,
    numbered_from(Xs, X1).
```

This is similar to Paulo's solution, but avoids the problem that variable ordering is only required by ISO/IEC 13211-1 to be consistent within a single execution of `sort/2`.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, **less** efficient than Tudor's clever solution and thus **not** recommended, but still worth mentioning here as I see it being used on multiple occasions, is:

```
varset_seteq(As, Bs) :-
    sort(As, Sa), sort(Bs, Sb), Sa == Sb.
```

Comment: My original answer was just about that :), though I also had the addition of a `varlist/1` predicate to check if both lists were composed of variables. But then I realized, and Tudor Berariu pointed out, that this approach will succeed on, e.g., `As = [A,A,B,C], Bs = [B,C,B,C,A]`. I probably should have left my original attempt too..

Comment: While this solution will work in concrete Prolog implementations, it relies on implementation dependent properties of a Prolog implementation. At the goal `Sa == Sb` it is no longer guaranteed that `Sa` and `Sb` are still sorted. Think of a GC happening in an implementation that does not preserve variable ordering - which might still be conforming when it does not invoke GC during `sort/2`.

Comment: @aBathologist Indeed :-) Detailing pitfalls of apparent alternative solutions is always worth it. Nevertheless, the original question does state that the input is "two lists of *unique* variables" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @PauloMoura Oh yeah. You're right! My reading has been faltering back and forth between whether or not falsel meant the predicate itself should fail if the lists aren't "varsets", or if it can expect that its arguments will be varsets. Now, with your emphasis, it seems clear that it can expect varsets (just like `ord_seteq/1` expects, but does not test for, ordered sets).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach. If we provide ourselves with these higher order predicates (which are each useful on their own),

```
select_with(_, _, [], []).
select_with(P, X, [Y|Ys], Ys)     :- call(P, X, Y), !.
select_with(P, X, [Y|Ys], [Y|Ks]) :-
    select_with(P, X, Ys, Ks).

foldl(_,[],Vn,Vn).
foldl(P,[X|Xs],V0,Vn) :- 
    call(P,X,V0,V1),
    foldl_(P,Xs,V1,Vn).
```

then we can easily define a predicate that is true if each member one list has an equal element in the other (using `==/2`):

```
members_equal(A, B :-
    foldl(select_with(==), A, B, []).
```

This predicate can be specialized for the stated purpose if we verify that the incoming arguments are varsets. The following is the best I've been able to come up with in that direction (but it eats up quite a few inferences):

```
is_varset([]).
is_varset([V|Vs]) :-
    var(V),
    maplist(\==(V), Vs),
    is_varset(Vs).
```

(At least on SWI Prolog, using `sort/2` takes fewer inferences than the above. Presumably this is because the sorting is done in C. Also, this answer still doesn't approach the elegance of the `term_vars/2` approach——such is the power of "semantic ascent" :)